# Need "a leading '/' to generate a URL outside of a Razor Page"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

My solution has an AREA called 'Adm' and I have two controllers called AdmBanks and AdmBuildingTypes.
Both were generated by the VS Scaffolding tool, and worked just fine.
However, I am now adding Sort, Paging and Filtering (as per [this MS tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-2.0#add-paging-links-to-the-student-index-view)).

So I have modified the AdmBanks page accordingly.
the project builds fine, but when I try to run the AdmBanks page, I get the following error.

> InvalidOperationException: The relative page path 'Index' can only be
>   used while executing a Razor Page. Specify a root relative path with a
>   leading '/' to generate a URL outside of a Razor Page.
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.RenderAtEndOfFormTagHelper.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext
>   context, TagHelperOutput output)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.RunAsync(TagHelperExecutionContext
>   executionContext)
>   AspNetCore.Areas_Adm_Views_AdmBanks_Index.ExecuteAsync() in
>   Index.cshtml
>   +
>       ViewData["Title"] = "Index";   [1]:

My Index page starts with

```
@model FACEZ_Mvc.PaginatedList<FACEZ_Mvc.Models.AdmBank>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}
```

as instructed.

In line with the implied solution (see error message) I have tried the following: (None of which seem to make any difference.

```
ViewData["Title"] = "/Index";
ViewData["Title"] = "./Index";
ViewData["Title"] = "~/Index";
ViewData["Title"] = "AdmBanks/Index";
ViewData["Title"] = "/AdmBanks/Index";
ViewData["Title"] = "./AdmBanks/Index";
ViewData["Title"] = "../Index";
ViewData["Title"] = "../../Index";
```

How can I implement a dynamic route to my areas?
The (as yet untouched) 'AdmBuildingTypes' page still works without a hitch?